# Some question about algebraic group and Lie algebra action.

Tags: algebraic-geometry, lie-algebras, algebraic-groups

I have some basic question about algebraic group and Lie algebra actions which confuse me. Suppose that algebraic group $G$ acts on a variety $X$. Then $G$ acts on $\mathbb{C}[X]$ by $(g\cdot f)(x) = f(g^{-1} \cdot x)$, $x \in X$. Does the Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ of $G$ act on $\mathbb{C}[X]$? If yes, how does $\mathfrak{g}$ act on $\mathbb{C}[X]$? Thank you very much.

Comment: Should there be any relation between the action of $\mathfrak{g}$ and that of $G$? Otherwise, this is just asking whether some Lie algebra $\mathfrak{g}$ acts on some ring of functions $\mathbb C[X]$ of some variety $X$, which yes it does, e.g. with the trivial action $g \cdot f =0$ for all $g \in \mathfrak{g}, f\in \mathbb C[X]$.

Comment: @Torsten, yes, my question is about Lie algebra action which comes from the algebraic group action. Thank you very much.

Comment: But what do you mean, precisely, by "comes from"? If you have a definition or at least some conditions for that, it would probably answer your question. If you have no definition for that, your question makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 2):

It is basically the same as in differential geometry, except done algebraically.

The action of $G$ on the (infinite-dimensional) $\mathbb{C}$-vector space $\mathbb{C}[X]$ is an algebraic group homomorphism $G\to GL(\mathbb{C}[X])$.  So taking derivative gives $T_eG\to T_e(GL(\mathbb{C}[X]))$.  Identifying $T_eG$ with $\mathfrak{g}$ and $T_e(GL(\mathbb{C}[X]))$ with $\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{C}[X])$ then gives a Lie algebra homomorphism $\mathfrak{g}\to\mathfrak{gl}(\mathbb{C}[X])$.

If you are looking for a formula, it is the same as the differential geometry case: for $A\in\mathfrak{g}$, $f\in\mathbb{C}[X]$, $x\in X$, $v\in T_xX$, we have
$$
(A\cdot f)(x)=(v\mapsto -(T_x f)(Av))
$$

Comment: I'm confused by your formula. If we are viewing $A \in \mathfrak{g}$ as an element of $\mathfrak{g}\mathfrak{l}(\mathbb{C}[X])$, then shouldn't $(A \cdot f) \in \mathbb{C}[X]$? Instead it looks like a map from $X$ to $\mathbb{C}[T_x X]$ or something.

Answer (score 1):

$\DeclareMathOperator{\g}{\mathfrak{g}} \DeclareMathOperator{\complex}{\mathbb{C}}$ I can't parse the formula proposed by user10354138, so I am adding the formula I came to. For $A \in \mathfrak{g}$, $f \in \complex[X]$, $x \in X$, we have
$$
(A \cdot f)(x)=-d_x f(A x),
$$
where $d_x f (a)= \sum_{i} \frac{\partial f}{\partial t_i}(x) a_i$. Note that $(A \cdot f)\in \complex[X]$, as expected.

Note that this agrees with the familiar formula from differential geometry

$$
(A \cdot f)(x)=\frac{d}{d t}\left[f(e^{-t A} x)\right](0)=-d_x f(A x),
$$

where the last equality follows from the chain rule.

How do we see this formula? First note that the image of $G$ in $GL(\complex[X])$ is an algebraic group of $\complex$-algebra automorphisms of $\complex[X]$, so the image of $\mathfrak{g}$ in $\mathfrak{gl}(\complex[X])$ is a Lie algebra of derivations of $\complex[X]$. It follows that the action is uniquely defined by the action on the coordinate functions $(A \cdot t_i)$.

The above formula is clearly a derivation, so it suffices to compute $(A \cdot t_i)$ and show it agrees with the formula. WLOG assume $G\subseteq GL(n, \complex)$. Let $\phi: G \rightarrow GL(\complex[X])$ be the OP's homomorphism $\phi(g)(f)(x)=f(g^{-1}x)$. Then

$$
\phi(g)(t_i)=\sum_{j=1}^n g^{-1}(i,j) t_i.
$$

Since $\phi(g)$ preserves the subspace of linear polynomials for all $g \in G$, it suffices to compute the differential of $\phi$ as a map $G \rightarrow GL(\text{span}\{t_1,\dots, t_n\})$. With respect to the basis $\{t_1,\dots, t_n\}$, we have $\phi(g)=g^{-1}$, so $d_e \phi (A)=-A$, i.e.

$$
(A \cdot t_i)=d_e \phi(A)(t_i)=-\sum_{j=1}^n A(i,j) t_j,
$$

where the first equality is by definition. Now we just need to check that this agrees with the proposed formula: $-d_{e_j} t_i (A e_j)=-t_i(A e_j)=-A(i,j)$. QED

All we need is an algebraically closed field here.